# Proof that $\dim\text{span}\{x,x^2\cos x,\cos x\}=3$

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

I have the following question :

Let $V$ a space of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Proof that $\dim  \text{span}\{x,x^2\cos x,\cos x\}=3$.

For some reason I managed to show the opposite direction, this what I did :

Therefore I should show that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$$\lambda_1 x+\lambda_2x^2\cos x+\lambda_3 \cos x=0 \implies \lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$$

But for $x=0 \implies \lambda_3=0$ and $\lambda_1 \neq 0$ and also $\lambda_2 \neq 0$ Therefore we found $x$ that $\lambda_1 \neq 0$ and $\lambda_2 \neq 0$ so this group is linearly independent.

I don't quite understand the thing with the $x$ usually when I need to show linearly independent I get vectors not functions how should I handle it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Please, do not use any calculus (differentiation, integrals) since I'm not allowed to use it in order to solve the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: We say that the functions $f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)$ are linearly dependent if there exist coefficients $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ not all zero such that
$$
\sum \lambda_i f_i(x) = 0
$$
**for all** $x$.  Your function is only zero at one value of $x$, but the function $\sum \lambda_i f_i$ is not the zero function.

Comment: Equality must hold *for all* $x$, not just for $x=0$.

Comment: You must understand the equality.  The $=0$ means that these are equal as *functions*.  It is OK for the value of the LHS to be zero sometimes, it just can't *always* be zero.  The zero function is equal to zero for all inputs of $x$, so it's not enough for the LHS to be equal to zero at one point.

Comment: For example, if we take the function $f(x) = x$, the set $\{f\}$ is linearly independent even though $1 \cdot f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, So in order to show that the function are linearly independant, I should show that exist $x \in R$  so $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$ right?

Comment: @JaVaPG You have freedom to pick as many $x$ as you wish. If you manage to show at the end that all $\lambda$'s are zero then you are done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After showing $\lambda_3=0$ you have got: for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
\lambda_1x+\lambda_2x^2\cos x=0.
$$
Testing $x=\pi/2$ gives $\lambda_1=0$, thus, $\lambda_2x^2\cos x=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Testing $x=2\pi$ gives $\lambda_2=0$. Thus, all $\lambda_k=0$.

Comment: Isn't is enough to find one $x$ that implies that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$ inorder to show that the function is linearly independant?

Comment: One $x$ gives you only *one* equation for *three* unknown variables $\lambda$. You need at least three different values of $x$ to collect a linear system $A\lambda=0$ with an invertible matrix $A$ to prove independence.

Answer (score 1):

An other way to proving linear independence of  functions$\{ f_1(x), f_2(x) ,f_3(x)\}$ is proving that
$$ \begin{vmatrix}
 f_1(x)& f_2(x) &f_3(x) \\
f'_1(x)& f'_2(x) &f'_3(x)\\
f"_1(x)& f"_2(x) &f"_3(x)\end{vmatrix} \neq 0$$ simply you can use this. If the functions are independent so the dimension of their span will be equal to their number.

Comment: This determinant is known as the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian)

Comment: @Ali Just a remark. The "problem" with Wronskian is that it is only sufficient (in general). If $\det\equiv 0$ it *does not* mean that the functions are dependent.